# Colocalization in R / Cross-Correlation of 3D matrices

Tags: r, matrix, cross-correlation

I hope this has not been asked before, but I am currently in the process of analyzing some microscopy pictures in R and I am not quite sure how to tackle this.

The situation is as follows:
- I have several pictures of different targets in cells which show spots of signal
- Some pictures show the same cells, but were aquired after others and are therefore a little "off" in x-, y- and z-direction
- Some, but by no means all of the pictures show colocalization = spots from one picture also show up on other pictures

Coming from the spot detection software, I now have data frames for all spots in each picture (one df per picture) with the x-, y- and z-coordinates.

I am now looking for

a) a way to align these matrices of spots from the different colors and thought that cross-correlation of the matrices might be a way to go (however, is there CC in 3D in R?)

b) a way to calculate the colocalization. As these are pictures and intrinsically noisy, even colocalized spots might have a little different coordinates. Is there a function of package in R which merges these data based on a threshold or other parameter of my choice?

Thanks a lot in advance for all your answers!!
Simon

Comment: I see some packages that may be relevant http://www.rdocumentation.org/advanced_search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Colocalization&package_name=&function_name=&title=&description=&author=

Comment: unfortunately this is colocalization of genetic data, while I am looking for microscopy data :-/